# How to move image in flutter Card by small amount

Tags: android, flutter, image-size

I am making a flutter app and I am using the same image in two places. The first place is a carousel and the second is a Full size Container. The image in the carousel is being cut and I want to shift it slightly to the right so that it does not get cut from the text area.

Currently this is how it looks

[image]

I want to ensure that the box with the text is not cropped.

Below is the image for reference

[image]

This is the code I am using

```
child: Card(
                    elevation: 4,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          12.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        imageName,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: double.infinity,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the **alignment** property within the `Image.asset` widget.

To align it from the left, simply assign **alignment** as `Alignment.centerLeft`.

For more customization, you can set it from `Alignment(-1.0, 0.0)`, which represents `Alignment.centerLeft`, to `Alignment(0.0, 0.0)`, representing `Alignment.center`.

For example:

```dart
child: Image.asset(
  imageName,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  width: double.infinity,
  height: double.infinity,
),
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I tried the alignment widget everywhere but here

Answer (score 0):

Use `fit: BoxFit.contain`

you can also try the `FittedBox` Widget:

```
child: FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      child: Image.asset(
        imageName,
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: No this is not working it gives me the following error

Another exception was thrown: RenderClipRRect does not meet its constraints.
Another exception was thrown: RenderSemanticsAnnotations does not meet its constraints.
Another exception was thrown: _RenderInkFeatures does not meet its constraints.
Another exception was thrown: RenderCustomPaint does not meet its constraints.
Another exception was thrown: RenderPhysicalShape does not meet its constraints.

Altough if I just use the fit and not the fittedbox then it works as long as the image is exact size of the container